# Error - NZEC - C# - HackerEarth

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have a code which is working fine on my PC and in the console provided by HackerEarth as well(with custom input) but while submitting it on Hacker Earth, it is returning NZEC Runtime error in 2 test cases from 53. 
 [This is the problem description](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/multi-dimensional/practice-problems/algorithm/largest-square-3d7a938a/)
This is my solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static int xx1=-1, yy1=-1, xx2=-1, yy2=-1,dyy=-1;

    static  void store(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2,int dy)
    {
        dyy = dy;
        xx1 = x1;
        xx2 = x2;
        yy1 = y1;
        yy2 = y2;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var a = new Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var s = Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' ');
            var x = int.Parse(s[0]);
            var y = int.Parse(s[1]);
            if (a.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                a[x].Add(y);

            }
            else
            {
                var set = new SortedSet<int>();
                set.Add(y);
                a.Add(x,set);
            }
        }

            foreach(KeyValuePair<int, SortedSet<int>> entry in a)
            {
                var set = entry.Value;
                foreach (int j in set)
                {
                    foreach (int k in set)
                    {
                        if (k > j)
                        {
                            int y1 = j,x1=entry.Key,y2=k;
                            int dy = y2 - y1;
                            int x2 = x1 + dy;

                            if(a.ContainsKey(x2) && a[x2].Contains(y1) && a[x2].Contains(y2))
                            {
                                if (dy > dyy)
                                {
                                    store(x1,x2,y1,y2,dy);
                                }
                                else if (dy == dyy)
                                {
                                    if (y1 < yy1)
                                    {
                                        store(x1,x2,y1,y2,dy);
                                    }
                                    else if(y1 == yy1)
                                    {
                                        if (x1 < xx1)
                                        {
                                            store(x1,x2,y1,y2,dy);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        if (xx1 == -1) Console.WriteLine(-1);
            else Console.WriteLine(xx1+ " "+yy1);

    }
}
```

I think the problem is that too much memory is allocated for the Dictionary.
These are the 2 test cases for which I get runtime error:

```
46
886659200 6000017
11179348 563488904
112321278 512936341
290805893 582941743
981713638 730642556
451606487 821897906
276959357 3493184
348256888 724765346
631201209 265534133
805273482 835799625
7896278 780434096
558123206 298916496
125934025 501664595
3093907 153530369
259080509 243882571
925707583 116455092
424262818 15570209
317202859 428416515
385632830 648856356
430361226 642776630
946215093 428577508
232353771 924654484
210858703 358484249
413081322 682017430
11575422 767941993
771050757 810529689
379926076 348133307
122213626 91834874
71354138 418442988
209818788 131444731
498071620 348763190
33476125 229092671
804771068 917072705
519783854 347122605
119883416 521216836
286529548 492247353
228879775 837125515
532450512 150833406
941425991 107647662
232307150 352065548
737027784 217852390
678923524 583497416
713585999 587088651
448042752 460509778
135584007 849215265
120007541 541958087
```

This test case is pretty small, but it is returning error as well.

```
10
50 50
75 50
100 50
50 75
75 75
100 75
1000 1000
1000 1000
1000 1000
1000 1000
```